# Adjust x values on an effects plot using R

Tags: r, plot, trace, lattice, interaction

I'm working on an assignment, and I have to create an effects plot using a subset of data from all airlines from November 2008.  This is what I have:

```
library(lattice)

airline <- airline_cleaned

attach(airline)

airline$ArrDelay=log(ArrDelay+25.1)

selectAirlines <- subset(airline, UniqueCarrier=="AA" | UniqueCarrier=="UA" | UniqueCarrier=="NW")

attach(selectAirlines)


trace <- rep(1,length(selectAirlines$UniqueCarrier))

interaction.plot(selectAirlines$UniqueCarrier, trace, selectAirlines$ArrDelay, fun=mean, legend=F)
```

and here is the output:

[image: Effects plot output]

but my subset only has AA, UA and NW as UniqueCarrier types.  So, I don't understand why it's including all of the other types.

This is what it's kind of supposed to look like:

[image: Effects Plot Example]

Can someone help me understand this, and how to change it so it only shows AA, UA and NW?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: When you subset a factor, it still remembers all the possible levels. You can use `droplevels()` to forget about them, something like `ineraction.plot(droplevels(selectAirlines$UniqueCarrier), ...`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: you can highlight the code and use the `{}` button instead of backticks next time